# What are the likely causes of the same program running significantly slower on only slightly different machines?

Tags: windows, performance

I have a mix of Dell machines, all bought at the same time, with only slightly different specs. The Windows Experience index is almost identical.

Yet my program runs at a speed difference of 25-40% (i.e. really noticeable) on the machines.

They are all out-of-the-box business Dells, no extra programs running (not that take up significant resources anyway).

My program is graphics-based, loading in a lot of data and then processing it on the CPU. CPU usage is identical on all machines, I only use a single thread.

I'd expect maybe 5-10% variation based on the processors (according to benchmarks).

My programmer spidey-sense tells me that something is wrong here.

Is this going to be something like cache misses? Is there anything else I should be looking at?

Comment: It's really hard to guess based on the general details you provide.  Look at the key processing in your program, and try to create a small test program that reproduces the same behavior.

Comment: A lot of data accessed from the hdd? The i/o system is usually no 1 suspect. If your i/o count is high, location on the platters plus other random io activity will produce such variation. Check performance counters.

Comment: SO isn't really meant for "Here's a vague description of a generic problem. Can you speculate on all of the possible reasons it might be happening?" type questions. Do some basic troubleshooting on your own, or use a debugger to figure out what's going on, and then come back with a specific question about any issues you find. SO should be the *last resort* after you've done that troubleshooting, not the first for ideas on where to start.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to answer the question. It could be caused by many different things

Comment: @Eric J, yeah, I know, but it's >500K LOC and it's really just my experience based on seeing the program run on hundreds of different machines over the years that tells me there's an issue.

Comment: @Ken White, yes, you're right. I guess I'm looking for opinions really. *slaps self on hand*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used debugging programs such as WinDbg for these situations. There are a lot of tools in those programs to nail down where the exact bottleneck is. E.g. Run them side by side and identify which point the slower machine is lagging. If physical specs of the machines are identical, it is most likely some difference in network configuration if there is a bottleneck when it is downloading the graphics. In that case, a tool such as WireShark would show you what hops the application is taking over the network to retrieve the data. If netwrok configuration is identical, I wouldn't rule out a physcial problem with the machine such as faulty ram or dodgy network cable. Also, check out the running processes side by side and see if there is any difference, kill unnessessary tasks that may be taking up memory on the slower computer and remove if necessary.

Comment: I have multiples of all types of machines, so unless it's a problem with a batch of machines from Dell (unlikely IMO), it's probably not physical.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer just because it is the best thing to do to get more information to make this a fact-based question.